# Readonly property overrides required in form input

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have some required inputs in my form but I have to put a "readonly" property on them for some reason.
The problem is that when I do that, the "readonly" property takes the lead and I can submit my form without filling the fields I want to be filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Jquery solution to look for every required fields in a submitted form and prevent its submission if at least one of them is not filled:

```
  $('form').each(function() {
    var form = $(this)
    form.submit(function(e){
      form.find('[required]').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
          alert("Field not filled: " + $(this).attr('name'))
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      })
    })
  })
```